# How can I detect if a Chrome Extension has been enabled (after having been disabled)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Let's say a user disables my extension and then later enables it.

How can I run a function when the extension gets re-enabled?

I tried doing something akin to running a function on-extension-install, using localStorage, but it does not appear to work for this on-extension-reenabled case because localStorage doesn't get cleared for the background-page when it is disabled.

```
if (!localStorage["isInstalled"]) {
onInstall();
localStorage["isInstalled"] = 1;
}
```

Comment: From extension's and user's perspectives, disabling extension has exactly the same effect as closing a browser. Why would you need to distinguish those two cases?

Answer (score 4):

An extension on its own can't monitor when it gets disabled. You'd need a second extension to monitor this.

As a slight alternative, you could use `sessionStorage["isInstalled"] = 1;`, which would get cleared if the extension was disabled, **but** this would also be cleared if the user exited Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [management API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html#event-onEnabled), which lets you respond to events like `onEnabled`, firing when an app or extension has been enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately onEnabled is only triggered when other extensions are enabled. It does not fire when the extension itself is enabled.

Comment: What about nondisabled?  Does it get fired for it's own app?